# I am allowing partial refunds on my monero-integrated store, how do I prevent the fee being deducted from the balance that is left over?

Tags: daemon, monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, transaction-fees, payment-integration

I want the fee to be deducted from the refunded amount.

For example,

Given a fee of 1 XMR

If I refund 100 xmr from a 200xmr account, I would like the refunded amount to be 99 XMR (100-1) and the remaining balance to be 100 XMR. Currently, it is the opposite (the remaining balance would be 99 XMR, and the sent amount would 100 XMR).

How do I achieve this?